# How to upload my files on SVN through Tortoise SVN - Need to upgrade the working copy first

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

I feel like a douche for not being able to upload a simple directory to SVN.

I am using Tortoise SVN version 1.8.

I selected a folder and did a checkout from the SVN folder. When I had the existing folders, I added a new folder "New"  and did a commit (by right clicking the folder and Selecting SVN Commit). It showed all of the directory is uploaded or that's what I thought that everything should be uploaded. But it missed quite a lot of items.

When I right clicked again and did an SVN Commit, it showed a lot of non-versioned files. When I selected All and clicked Ok (to commit), it gave me the following error.

The working copy at the location is too old format (format 10) to work with client version 1.8.0 (it expects format 31). **You need to upgrade the working copy first**.

Could you help  that how can I upgrade the working copy first?

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try performing the "Clean up". Right click on your working copy and you'll get this option.

if it doesn't work make a backup, delete everything in your workingcopy including hidden files of .svn folder and then take latest. If you still get this error then repeat the clean up.

Comment: Every information related to svn is kept in the files in .svn folder you can delete them but you'll loose your bindings and you've to rebind the stuff again.